# Transfering a Time Machine Backup to a Macbook Already in Use

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, time-machine

It seems like my MBP (15in, 2019) is nearing the end of its life–or at least its life off of the charger. I do weekly backups just in case and I have another MBP (14in, M2 Max) that I'd like to transfer to if/whenever the first gives out. I've been using the second laptop as an editing station since I got it and I may need to switch to taking that one with me wherever I go. The trouble is I've only seen Time Machine documentation for restoring backups to a *new* laptop. **Is it possible to import my Time Machine backup from my old MBP, while keeping the data I've written on the M2?**